# How to really close connection or disconnect in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, server, connection, ssms, disconnect

When closing a connection in Sql Server Management Studio 18 the connection disappears from the Object Explorer. It makes me think that the connection does not exist anymore.

[image]

However, if I still have a query tab open (that used that connection before I closed it) I can still execute that query after pressing that disconnection button. So the connection is still alive!

Is there a way to prevent that? Some setting that really kills the server connection?

Comment: You have disconnected in the object explorer, not the query. They are **separate** connections. Each query window uses it's *own* connection.

Comment: If you want to disconnect a query window, right-click inside it, then select Connection -> Disconnect. It will disconnect *that* query window. If you want to disconnect the all, select Disconnect all Queries. Or, alternatively, go to Query -> Connection in the toolbar.